# Show "last Chatter date" on parent record?

Tags: apex, trigger, chatter, administration, custom-field

Anyone know of a way to store (akin to Modification Date, etc) the '**last Chatter date**' on a record (Account, Lead, Contact, or especially Case)?  Perhaps a canned Trigger someone has made if it's not built into SF?  I have searched and find no refernces to this ability.  :-/

Thanks.

Comment: Any luck with getting this working?

Comment: Actually, just came across this:

http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/lastchatterdate

Comment: Thanks for the link.   I am doing VERY little Dev work now, as we've hired a fulltime Dev-dedicated person thankfully, so I can focus on Architecture and Administration.  That link is basically priceless since it literally hands the code over.   Thanks again @JustAGirlyGeek !!

Comment: Happy to help! Figured I'd share in case anyone else comes across this post in the future since I had the same question about how to configure.

Comment: One frustration I'm now running into:  The code does not ALWAYS update the datetime field.  (sigh)   Trying to figure it out now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Create a custom last Modified chatter date field on Account, Lead, Contact  and  Case
2. Create a trigger on FeeItem (`Setup > Chatter > Triggers > FeedItem Triggers` )
3. Inside the trigger, perform a Describe on the **parentids** in question to ascertain whether or not the the custom  'last Modified chatter date' exists **edit**: ..and to ascertain the object name(s) to facilitate building the update collections from SOQL.
4. On those records where the  field exists , update with the the current date/time

Comment: The describe isn't really necessary, though; the system will give you an error if it doesn't exist, and you can capture that error and ignore it. But this is a great idea.

Comment: Thanks for the thumbs up @sfdcfox . I have expanded on point 3 in my answer.

Comment: @sfdcfox - I stand corrected as per your excellent answer on http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22812/instantiate-an-instance-of-the-sobject-type - indeed, no Describe necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the time spent relaying this answer.  @JustAGirlyGeek also got a link for the canned code.  Awesome help, all  ;)  Passing this to my Dev now.